# Saber index de una Nodelist con algun atributo

Tags: javascript, index

**HTML**

Elemento 1

Elemento 2

Elemento 3

**JS**

Const elementos = document.querySelectorAll("p");

elementos.indexOf("Elemento 1"); **Esto no me sirvió**

Comment: Pon el código real del asunto

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

creo saber qué es lo que deseas; al igual que el método de los `Arrays`, con el método `indexOf` que busca el primer índice que coincida con un elemento del array, deseas buscar el primer elemento de la `NodeList` que contenga el texto que le pasas a al método `indexOf`. Este metodo solo viene en los `Arrays` por lo que a mi parecer hay dos soluciones:

### Agregar el método `IndexOf` al `prototype` de las `NodeList`

```js
NodeList.prototype.indexOf = function (string) {
  const index = [...this].findIndex((element) => {
    return element.textContent === string
  })
  return index
}
```

En una constante `paragraphs` guardamos la `NodeList` que `querySelectorAll` nos devuelve.
Al `prototype` de la clase `NodeList` le agregamos el método `indexOf` que recibirá el parámetro `string` el cual será una cadena texto *(A diferencia del original de los arrays que puede ser de varios tipos)*.

Ahora en la constante `index` se guardara el índice del elemento que contenga el texto de `string`. Para ello usaremos la funcion `findIndex` que solo se puede usar de los `Arrays` por lo que usaremos el `Spread Operator (...)` para agregar a un nuevo arreglo la `NodeList`, esto lo hacemos con `this`, ya que es la lista de elementos.

Esta función recibe como parámetro un callback que retornara un boolean, y cuando retorne un `true` la iteración se detendrá y devolverá el índice del elemento que iba recorriendo.
Entonces en esta funcion callback retornaremos la comparación del `textContent` de cada elemento con el `string` que se pasó por parámetro.

Ahora solo queda retornar el index que se encontró.

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')

console.log(paragraphs.indexOf('')) // -1
console.log(paragraphs.indexOf('Elemento 1')) // 0
console.log(paragraphs.indexOf('Elemento 2')) // 1
console.log(paragraphs.indexOf('Elemento 3')) // 2
console.log(paragraphs.indexOf('Elemento 4')) // -1
```

```html
<p>Elemento 1</p>
<p>Elemento 2</p>
<p>Elemento 3</p>
```

### Buscando con `findIndex` en lugar de `indexOf`

Como dije anteriormente, el método `findIndex` es propio de los `Arrays`, por lo que para usarlo a la constante `paragraphs` le asignaremos una nuevo array y usaremos el `spread operator (...)` para agregar la `NodeList`.

Ahora solos nos queda guardar en la constante `index` el índice que devuelva este método, de igual manera comparando el `textContent` del elemento con la cadena que en este caso quieras buscar.

```js
const paragraphs = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]

const index = paragraphs.findIndex(element => {
  return element.textContent === 'Elemento 1'
})

console.log(index) // 0
```

```html
<p>Elemento 1</p>
<p>Elemento 2</p>
<p>Elemento 3</p>
```

**También puedes encapsularlo en una función**

```js
const paragraphs = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]

const findIndexOfElement = (nodeList, string) => {
  const index = nodeList.findIndex(element => {
    return element.textContent === string
  })
  return index
}

const index = findIndexOfElement(paragraphs, 'Elemento 1')

console.log(index)
```